# TreeItem text wraps up if text contains carriage return

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

If text contains any carriage return (say "Hello\r\n Hi"), on setting this text to TreeItem as node item, displays only the text which is before carriage return (ex. "Hello"). I am not sure if there are any limitation with Tree Data Binding if text contains any special characters.

Is this the predefined behavior for TreeItem to truncate text after carriage return character ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [SWT Snippet](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/): [Table example snippet: draw multiple lines of text in a table item](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/plain/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet231.java). Although it is for tables, the same holds true for trees.